# Applying lambda function to multiple columns with IF statement to leave blanks as-is

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am working with a dataset where a few interger columns have two extra zeros at the end of each number. As such, I wrote a lambda function to remove them:

```
df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']] = df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda value: '{:,.2f}'.format(value/100)))
```

However, some values in each column are blanks, which yields a *ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.* error. Therefore, if possible, I want to add an IF statement inside the lambda function that would leave blanks as-is.

Based on another post, I tried the following:

```
df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']] = df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']].apply(lambda x: None if x.empty else x.apply(lambda value: '{:,.2f}'.format(value/100)))
```

But it yields the same error. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. However, you need to put the check inside the second lambda function and improve the check for number values. This code should work:

```py
import numbers
df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']] = df[['col_8', 'col_9', 'col_10']].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda value: ('{:,.2f}'.format(value/100)) if isinstance(value, numbers.Number) else None))
```